# SearchView doesn't show the VoiceButton

Tags: java, android, xml, voice

Hi I am trying to create the Searchview with the items like in the Android Documentation:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#VoiceSearch

The Searchview works but doesn't show the Voicebutton.
As you can see I added all things. But something is missing or wrong.
Isn't the most important line android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"/>?

The docs:
The value showVoiceSearchButton is required to enable voice search, while the second value, launchRecognizer, specifies that the voice search button should launch a recognizer that returns the transcribed text to the searchable activity.

Hope for some help. thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"/>
```

```
  <menu
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/menu_main"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_stat_name"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_custom_one"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="@string/test"
        android:visible="true"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_custom_two"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:title="@string/test"
        android:visible="true"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

```
 @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater menuInflater) {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);

        final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);    
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        newText = newText.toLowerCase();
        List<Food> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Food foodList : mFoodList) {
            String name = String.valueOf(foodList.getHeader()).toLowerCase();
            if (name.contains(newText)) {
                list.add(foodList);
            }
        }
        mRecyclerAdapter.setFilter(list);
        return true;
    }
```

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Base">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
</activity>
```